# Filtering results given html file

Tags: html, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to filter results by some criteria having a big html. I don't know if what I am trying to ask is achievable, but it costs nothing to ask.
I'm playing a browser game which as a big map 100x100 and for each pixel it has an island. Each island has a different cave ( of different materials, but I am only interested on a determined material ) and a carpentry and each island has 16 free slots.
I would like to find an island with no more than 7 occupied slots and of these, which has the highest level of carpentry and mine.
Each island html is structured like this :

```
<div id="tile_12_10" class="islandTile island2" style="left: 240px; top: 1320px; display: block;" title="Nyeos [71:92]">
   <div id="marking_12_10" class=""></div>
   <div id="wonder_12_10" class="wonder wonder1"><span class="ikaeasy-resource ikaeasy-resource-wonder ikaeasy-t-20 ikaeasy-l--20 ikaeasy-d-n">5</span></div>
   <div id="tradegood_12_10" class="tradegood tradegood2"><span class="ikaeasy-resource ikaeasy-resource-mine ikaeasy-l--20 ikaeasy-d-n">16</span></div>
   <div id="cities_12_10" class="cities">16</div>
   <div id="piracy_12_10" class=""></div>
   <div id="helios_12_10" class=""></div>
   <div id="magnify_12_10"></div>
   <div id="owner_12_10" class="ownerState "></div>
   <a href="javascript:ikariam.getScreen().clickIsland('tile_12_10');" id="linkurl_12_10" class="linkurl"></a>
   <div class="ikaeasy-resource ikaeasy-resource-wood ikaeasy-b-70 ikaeasy-l-55 ikaeasy-d-n">
      <div class="ikaeasy-resource-icon ikaeasy-w-24 ikaeasy-h-20" style="background-image: url(skin/resources/icon_wood.png);"></div>
      <span>21</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

The results I'm interested are:
For the cave, as I said, I'm only interested to find the island with a specific material, and the latter is specified in the html in the class ***tradegood tradegood2***. So that **2** is the specific materials the island produces. After that, the level of cave is determine in the ***class*** `ikaeasy-resource ikaeasy-resource-mine ikaeasy-l--20 ikaeasy-d-n` which contains the "16" level.
For the wood( carpentry ), the ***div class*** `ikaeasy-resource ikaeasy-resource-wood ikaeasy-b-70 ikaeasy-l-55 ikaeasy-d-n` which contains the "21" level.
For the occupied slots, the ***div*** `cities_12_10` which contains `class="cities"` which is "16", which means the island has not free slots.

Would be possible to get all the island that has that specific material, no more than 7 slots occupied, and to sort these for the highest cave and carpentry levels?
something like

> Island [71:92] mine : lvl  16 carpentry : lvl 20 free slots: 9

p.s. The class class="oceanTile " is pure ocean so no island in there.

p.s.2 since **<div id="tile_12_10"** changes for every island, i'm adding `and starts-with(@id, 'tile_')]")` at the first for each.
I'm using html agility pack library and this is what i've been able to write so far

```
Imports System.IO
Imports HtmlAgilityPack

Public Class Form1
    Public Class Island
        Public Property Coord As String
        Public Property MineLevel As Integer
        Public Property CarpentryLevel As Integer
        Public Property FreeSlots As Integer
    End Class
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
        htmlDoc.Load("pastebin.html")
                    ' Get all islandTile elements that have a trade good type of 2 (tradegood2)

        Dim islands As New List(Of Island)()

       For Each tile As HtmlNode In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class, 'islandTile') and not(contains(@class, 'oceanTile')) and starts-with(@id, 'tile_')]")

            ' Check if this island produces the specific material you're interested in
            Dim tradeGoodType As String = tile.SelectSingleNode(".//div[contains(@class, 'tradegood')]/@class")?.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
            If tradeGoodType <> "tradegood tradegood2" Then
                Continue For
            End If

            ' Get the levels of mine and carpentry
            Dim mineLevel As Integer
            Integer.TryParse(tile.SelectSingleNode(".//div[contains(@class, 'tradegood2')]/span")?.InnerText, mineLevel)
            Dim carpentryLevel As Integer
            Integer.TryParse(tile.SelectSingleNode(".//div[contains(@class, 'ikaeasy-resource-wood')]/span")?.InnerText, carpentryLevel)

            ' Get the number of occupied slots
            Dim occupiedSlots As Integer
            Integer.TryParse(tile.SelectSingleNode(".//div[contains(@class, 'cities')]/text()")?.InnerText, occupiedSlots)

            ' Check if the island meets the criteria and add it to the list
            If occupiedSlots <= 7 Then
                Dim island As New Island With {
                    .Coord = tile.GetAttributeValue("title", ""),
                    .MineLevel = mineLevel,
                    .CarpentryLevel = carpentryLevel,
                    .FreeSlots = 16 - occupiedSlots
                }
                islands.Add(island)
            End If
        Next

        ' Sort the islands by cave level (descending) and then by carpentry level (descending)
        islands = islands.OrderByDescending(Function(i) i.MineLevel).ThenByDescending(Function(i) i.CarpentryLevel).ToList()

        ' Print the results
        For Each island In islands
            Debug.Print("Island " & island.Coord & " mine: lvl " & island.MineLevel & " carpentry: lvl " & island.CarpentryLevel & " free slots: " & island.FreeSlots)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

but nothing happens when i press the button...

I pasted the entire html in a [pastebin file](https://pastebin.com/MmA6zwtN) if it could give any help.
Much appreciated

Comment: Many things are possible in many ways.  Out of curiosity, why have you chosen to use the html-agility-pack?

Comment: I didn't know anything better to manipulate html.. But if you have a better way, here you go :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

```
Imports System.IO
Imports HtmlAgilityPack

Public Class Form1
    Public Class Island
        Public Property Coord As String
        Public Property MineLevel As Integer
        Public Property CarpentryLevel As Integer
        Public Property FreeSlots As Integer
    End Class
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
        htmlDoc.Load("kappa.html")
        ' Ottieni tutti gli elementi islandTile che hanno il tipo di materiale 2 (tradegood2)
        Dim islands As New List(Of Island)()

        For Each tile As HtmlNode In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class, 'islandTile') and not(contains(@class, 'oceanTile')) and starts-with(@id, 'tile_')]")

            ' Check if this island produces the specific material you're interested in
            Dim tradeGoodType As String = tile.SelectSingleNode(".//div[contains(@class, 'tradegood')]/@class")?.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
            If tradeGoodType <> "tradegood tradegood2" Then
                Continue For
            End If

            ' Get the levels of mine and carpentry
            Dim mineLevel As Integer
            Integer.TryParse(tile.SelectSingleNode(".//div[contains(@class, 'tradegood2')]/span")?.InnerText, mineLevel)
            Dim carpentryLevel As Integer
            Integer.TryParse(tile.SelectSingleNode(".//div[contains(@class, 'ikaeasy-resource-wood')]/span")?.InnerText, carpentryLevel)

            ' Get the number of occupied slots
            Dim occupiedSlots As Integer
            Integer.TryParse(tile.SelectSingleNode(".//div[contains(@class, 'cities')]/text()")?.InnerText, occupiedSlots)

            ' Check if the island meets the criteria and add it to the list
            If occupiedSlots <= 7 Then
                Dim island As New Island With {
                    .Coord = tile.GetAttributeValue("title", ""),
                    .MineLevel = mineLevel,
                    .CarpentryLevel = carpentryLevel,
                    .FreeSlots = 16 - occupiedSlots
                }
                islands.Add(island)
            End If
        Next

        ' Sort the islands by cave level (descending) and then by carpentry level (descending)
        islands = islands.OrderByDescending(Function(i) i.MineLevel).ThenByDescending(Function(i) i.CarpentryLevel).ToList()

        ' Print the results
        For Each island In islands
            Debug.Print("Island " & island.Coord & " mine: lvl " & island.MineLevel & " carpentry: lvl " & island.CarpentryLevel & " free slots: " & island.FreeSlots)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```